# Collect tracking code is not working properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, einstein-recommendations, email-tracking

I'm currently implementing the collect tracking code to capture the User info wherein I'm able to get the user's email id into the tracking data extension (***IGO_PROFILES***) but not able to capture the additional attributes (*custom*) likes first name or Campaign name of the user

I've included below code into my webpage,

```
_etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {
            "email": "ABC@gmail.com",
            "details": {
                "first_name": "ABC",
                "Campaign": "testCampaign"
            }
        }]);
```

Please let me know if I missed anything into above tacking code, due to which I'm  not able to capture the additional attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These additional attributes will NOT be written/pushed to the `IGO_PROFILES` DE.

> Customer Attributes cannot be exported and currently do not get passed into Marketing Cloud data extensions. The primary use cases for these values are to seed Contact Attribute Affinity and to use these values in rules in influence recommendations. For example, a financial institution adds AgeGroup as Minor for some users, and then creates a rule that prohibits the recommendation engine from recommending items whereOfferType=CreditCard when AgeGroup = Minor.

However you can visualize them by going to Reporting > Contacts within Personalization Builder.  These additional attributes can also be leveraged in Rule Manager, a Tag Scenario,  and will also help [build affinity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_set_contact_attribute_affinity.htm&type=5) for recommendations.

> Match a contact attribute to a tagged catalog field to increase the subscriber's affinity for the value of that contact attribute. The amount of increase is less than what results from a purchase but more than the increase from a view.

Comment: Thank you so much @EazyE for this information

Comment: When you say "match a contact attribute to a tagged catalog field", do you mean the key for an attribute in the "details" object should match a key that is pushed in the "updateItem" object?