# Can I use Collect.js to log custom metadata into a data extention?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

We are about to implement Collect.js for cart abandonment purposes.
We need to update a case in SF Core related to the cart creation.

Therefore I was thinking of passing the case ID using the collect.js.
However, I could not find any documentation on customization of the data passed, nor a way to save it into a DE.

I did find information about [Affinity](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ctc_set_contact_attribute_affinity.htm&type=5) and this [case](https://%20https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/284509/collect-tracking-code-is-not-working-properly), but it seems the custom data isn't available on any DE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use *collect.js* for collecting custom data, as whatever it collects must be linked to your product catalogue by a valid SKU/item ID. Additional profile attributes will not be stored in any data extension, but only used for  predictions.

You can create your own "collect code" utilising either a JSON or JS code resource, which you can trigger within your website (e.g. by using Google Tag Manager). The data passed on to this code resource can then be pushed to SF Core utilising [CreateSalesforceObject](https://ampscript.guide/createsalesforceobject/) function in Ampscript.

This function can receive data from your website as URL parameters, which you can retrieve by utilising [RequestParameter](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/) function in Ampscript.

Keep in mind, that Code Resources, unlike regular Cloud Pages, don't consume super messages.

Comment: Thanks,@Lukas. You answered my main question, **You can't use collect.js for collecting custom data**. I'd prefer to use SQL or API call into a DE to get the case ID. And to update it I'd rather use Journey Builder native tile for it.

Comment: @yoni349 remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful